# VBScript & C# Read/Write XML WITHOUT locking file

Tags: c#, file, networking, vbscript, locking

Scenario:

1. Network User logs in to Domain
2. Group Policy runs a VBScript
3. VBScript reads from an XML
4. VBScript performs operations based in information obtained from XML

What VBScript method(s) should I use so that over a network with multiple users accessing the XML at the same time I will not be prone to file locking issues?

If I made a C# program to read-in and modify the existing XML file from a network location during operation hours (at the same time the XML is being read from) which C# methods should I use to read/write to the XML without causing locking issues?

Comment: There is no way to allow writes without locking the file (since user B could read the file, user A could write to the file, then user B write the file resulting in the loss of user A's records).  You will need to create a service which can manage requests.  An easier option is to use a SQL Server instead of an XML service.

Comment: I need to be more specific on this:

Comment: You could add a tag field to the XML file, indicating if it's currently in use, and possibly by which account for debugging/tracking purposes. When in use, set relevant field's tag to 1, when it's done, the script changes it to 0. Add a wait in your VBS. This approach may be considered a hack but it should work unless your script takes a long time to run, or if you have huge # of users accessing XML at same time. In that case, switch to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

For the C# program accessing the XML file you can do the following:

1. To handle XML file read/write requests use backgroundWorker component
2. add all the corresponding event handlers to know about progress updates etc.
3. call RunWorkerAsync to start read/write operation.

Source : [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ck8bc5c6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I not see why this s'd be so complicated. Just operate with 2 files.

- VBScript read from file *A1.xml*
- C# program write/update file *A2.xml* and then done replace *A1.xml*

And the vbs may look like...

```
Set xmlDoc   = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
xmlDoc.Async = False
bReturn      = False
Do Until bReturn
    WScript.Sleep 3500
    bReturn = xmlDoc.Load(".../A1.xml")
Loop
'...
```

Comment: please add param list () to the .Load call.